# Cannot send SMS in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, flutter-web

I am creating a web app in flutter. It is used for entering students' attendance into the database.
What I want to achieve is to send SMS to the parents of absent students. I came upon `flutter_sms 2.3.1` and it is supported for `Android`, `iOS` and `web` as per the `pub.dev` docs but I could not find any reference about sending SMS in flutter web using the same package. Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this task that I want.

Following is the code for sending the SMS but not working in Flutter web.

```
 void _sendSMS(String message, List<String> recipents) async {
 String _result = await sendSMS(message: message, recipients: recipents)
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
print(_result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio API would totally help you sending sms/whatsapp messages from any plaform automatically